# Do I add my dependent variable to PCA?

Tags: pca

I am performing a PCA, and have a small handful of dependent variables and a large number of recorded independent variables.

Do I perform the PCA on the independent variables and then correlate the dependent variables with the principal components or do I include ALL of the variables in the PCA?

Comment: What is the purpose of PCA in your case? Will classification follow on the components? Or is the PCA done for exploratory purposes only?

Comment: It depends on your purposes here, as @ArmenAghajanyan alludes. But it would be very unusual to include both IVs & DVs in 1 PCA. You might do 2 PCAs (1 for IVs, & 1 for DVs). You could also do [canonical correlation analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_correlation), which could sort of be seen as a generalization of PCA.

Comment: @ArmenAghajanyan , my PCA is to take 30 measured environmental parameters and see how they affect bacterial abundance.  But several of the parameters (e.g. Dissolved Oxygen, Water Temp) likely co-vary or (eg. Wind speed, Wind gusts) cause similar changes in the bacteria.    Ultimately would be nice to generate a statistical model, with PC rather than individual parameters.

Answer (score 5):

No, you don't need to include response variables.

The (major) purpose for PCA is to find directions that could spread data as much as possible, and some dimensions can be eliminated. 
There is a natural correspondence for the data after PCA dimension reduction. If the original data is $n$-by-$d$, and after dimension reduction, it becomes  $n$-by-$d'$. So the correspondence to the response variables does not change.

To incorporate response information, you may what to look for [LDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis) or [QDA](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_classifier).